# How to answer this composite function question?

Tags: group-theory, notation, symmetric-groups

Can any one answer this question please, I know it is a composite function but I don't understand this format at all.

$$A =\{ 1,2,3,4,5,6 \}$$

Compute $(4,1,3,5) \circ ( 5,6,2)$.

Comment: E.g. (5,6,2) is a cykel denoting the function prescribed by $5\mapsto6$, $6\mapsto 2$ and $2\mapsto 5$ and sending the others  numbers $1,3,4$ to themselves.

Answer (score 1):

$(4,1,3,5)$ is a mapping that sends $4 \to 1; 1 \to 3; 3\to 5; 5\to 4$ and the rest, $2,6$ are left alone.

$(5,6,2)$ is a mapping that sends $5\to 6; 6\to 2; 2\to 5$.

$(4,1,3,5)\circ(5,6,2)$ is the composition function it is the result of first doing $(5,6,2)$ and then  doing $(4,1,3,5)$ on the result.

So $5$ is sent to $6$ and then left alone.  So $5\to 6$.  $6$ is sent to $2$ and then left alone.  So $6 \to 2$.  $2$ is sent to $5$ which is then sent to $4$.  So $2\to 4$.  $4$ is first left alone and then $4$ is sent to $1$.  So $4\to 1$.  $1\to 1 \to 3$ so $ 1\to 3$.  $3\to 3 \to 5$ so $3\to 5$.  And $5\to 6$ is where we started from.

So we have $5\to 6; 6\to 2; 2\to 4;4\to 1; 1\to 3$ and $3\to 5$.  So the result is:

$(5,6,2,4,1,3)$

So $(4,1,3,5)\circ(5,6,2)=(5,6,2,4,1,3)$